# How to compose "Given" clauses using inheritance in C# and MSTest

Tags: c#, inheritance, testing, coding-style, mstest

I've seen many Java developers implementing the **Given part of a test** using a test inheritance.

For instance:
Imagine this statement in the GIVEN-WHEN-THEN form:

**Given** we have an Employee

- That has the Standard hourly Rate
- and Time cards just under overtime
- with a pay disposition of PayMaster
- and today is Friday

**When** Payroll is Run

**Then** they PayMaster will have a check for hours worked times hourly rate.

This could be written using these classes:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class PayrollTest {

public static abstract class GivenAnEmployee {

    Employee employee;

    @Before
    public void givenAnEmployee() {
        employee = new Employee("Bob");
    }    
}

public static abstract class GivenHourlyPayTypeEarningStandardRate extends GivenAnEmployee {
    HourlyPayType hourlyPayType;
    final int standardHourselyRate = 1000;

    @Before
    public void givenHourlyPayTypeEarningStandardRate() {
        hourlyPayType = new HourlyPayType(standardHourlyRate);
        employee.setPayType(hourlyPayType)
    }               
}

public static abstract class GivenTimecardsAddUpTolessThanOvertime extends GivenHourlyPayTypeEarningStandardRate {
    static final int daysPerWeek = 5;
    static final int maxRegularHoursPerDay = 8;

    @Before
    public void givenTimecardsAddUpToLessThanOvertime() {
        for (int day = 0; day < daysPerWeek; day++) {
            hourlyPayType.AddTimeCard(new Timecard(maxRegularHoursPerDay));
        }
    }              
}

public static abstract class GivenPaymasterDisposition extends GivenTimecardsAddUpTolessThanOvertime {
    @Before
    public void givenPaymasterDisposition() {
        employee.setDisposition(new PayMasterDisposition())
    }
}

public static class GivenTodayIsFriday extends GivenPaymasterDisposition {
    private Calendar today;

    @Before
    public void givenTodayIsFriday() {
        today = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.AUGUST, 9)
    }

    @Test 
    public void whenPayRollIsRun_ThenPaymasterWillHoldCheckForHoursWorkedTimesHourlyRate() throws Exception {
        Payroll payroll = new Payroll();
        payroll.add(employee);
        payroll.run(today);
        PayMaster payMaster = new employee.getPayMaster();
        List<PayCheck> checks = payMaster.getHeldPayChecks();
        assertEquals(1, checks.size));
        PayCheck check = checks.get(0);
        assertEquals(standardHourlyRate * maxRegularHoursPerDay * daysPerWeek, check.getAmount());                    
    }
}
```

}

Do you see it? It composes the statement. Each class executes its @Before method.

**How would this look in C#?**

I would like to do the same using MSTest (from Visual Studio). How? I don't know if the attributes [TestInitialize], [TestClass]… could behave to achieve the same result.

> NOTE: This example is proposed by Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob), author
>   of Clean Code.

Comment: Could you post the whole test class here if it's not too long? (as text, not a picture)

Comment: In my experience, TestInitialize behaves exactly the same way as described [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) for the Before annotation. If one test class inherits from another, and both a have method marked TestInitialize, then TestInitialize in the base class runs first. Note that both the base and derived classes must be marked with the TestClass attribute.

Comment: Please, take a look to the updated question above :) Thanks!